# Get last n months data from a relative date in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have 2 tables

Table 1

| Customer | Date_last_transacted |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2021-08-06 |
| B | 2007-09-02 |

Table 2

| Customer | Transactionid | TransactionDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 123 | 2021-08-06 |
| B | 234 | 2007-09-02 |
| A | 356 | 2014-09-09 |
| B | 456 | 2003-08-03 |
| A | 4567 | 2017-08-23 |
| A | 2244 | 2021-08-07 |
| A | 45678 | 2021-07-21 |

Table 1 is derived from table2 using max(transactionDate)

I want to select all rows in table 2 that are 24 months before date_last_transacted for that particular customer.

So, the result I want to get from table 2 is:
Table 2

| Customer | Transactionid | TransactionDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 123 | 2021-08-06 |
| B | 234 | 2007-09-02 |
| A | 2244 | 2021-08-07 |
| A | 45678 | 2021-07-21 |

Can you please help with the code?

Comment: What are some of the options you've tried?

Comment: SELECT * from Table2 where TransactionDate between (Date_last_transacted-730)
  and Date_last_transacted

Comment: Isn't Date_last_transacted for Customer A in Table 1 '2021-08-07'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following join query:

```
SELECT T.Customer, T.Transactionid, T.TransactionDate
FROM Table2 T
JOIN
(
  SELECT Customer, MAX(TransactionDate) Date_last_transacted
  FROM Table2
  GROUP BY Customer
) D
ON T.TransactionDate > DATEADD(Month, -24, D.Date_last_transacted) AND
   T.Customer = D.Customer
ORDER BY T.Transactionid
```

Also, you may use the `MAX` window function as the following:

```
SELECT Customer, Transactionid, TransactionDate
FROM
  (
    SELECT *,
       MAX(TransactionDate) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer) Date_last_transacted
    FROM Table2
  ) T
WHERE TransactionDate > DATEADD(Month, -24, Date_last_transacted)
ORDER BY Transactionid
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/_cgK2bNu).

Comment: Thank you! I think I missed adding the DateAdd fn

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to filter rows using the subquery and the DATEADD function.

```sql
SELECT * FROM Table2 T2
  WHERE
    DATEADD(month, 24, T2.transactionDate) >=
    ( SELECT MAX(T1.transactionDate) FROM Table2 T1
      WHERE T1.Customer=T2.Customer GROUP BY T1.Customer );
```

Comment: Thank you, i tried it with the DateAdd fn and it works!